# /*# sourceMappingURL=modal.css.map */ - что значит?

Tags: javascript, css

В `modal.css` прописана строчка в конце файла

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=modal.css.map */.
```

В консоле пишет:

GET http://landinco.ru/wp-content/themes/Divi/albanza/css/modal.css.map 404 (Not Found).

Что это означает и где взять ее? В скрипте такого файла нет...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это значит, что данный CSS код был сгенерирован с помощью какого-то CSS-препроцессора с использованием Карты Кода(Source Map).
Если в этом файле тебе всё понятно(или разбираться в нём не нужно) и работает он корректно, то эту строку можно смело удалить.

Прочитать про карты кода можно тут http://habrahabr.ru/post/148098/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а не подскажите, где более подробно почитать на эту тему?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.